# React Refactoring component with too many props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, refactoring

I have a component "Collage", which renders 4 types of images: BANNER, SQUARE, PORTRAIT and POSTER.

```
function Collage({ banner, square, portrait, poster }) {
   return (
       <View>
           <Image uri={banner?.uri} style={styles.banner} />
           <Image uri={square?.uri} style={styles.square} />
           <Image uri={portrait?.uri} style={styles.portrait} />
           <Image uri={poster?.uri} style={styles.poster} />
       </View>
   );
}

Collage.propTypes = {
    banner: PropTypes.shape({
        uri: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }),
    square: PropTypes.shape({
        uri: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }),
    portrait: PropTypes.shape({
        uri: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }),
    poster: PropTypes.shape({
        uri: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }),
}
```

Now, I wanna add the functionality of doing something (different for each image) when pressing the collage images.

Something like:

```
 <Collage 
    banner={banner}
    onPressBanner={handleOnPressBanner}
    square={square}
    onPressSquare={handleOnPressSquare}
    portrait={portrait}
    onPressPortrait={handleOnPressPortrait}
    poster={poster}
    onPressPoster={handleOnPressPoster}
 />


 ...

 function Collage({ banner, onPressBanner ... }) {
   return (
       <View>
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressBanner}>
              <Image uri={banner?.uri} style={styles.banner} />
           </TouchableOpacity>

           ... repeat for others
       </View>
   );
}
```

It seems unprofessional code, in my opinion, and there might be a way to make it simpler, with less props and more generalization. Any ideas?

Comment: You can create a `<CustomImage />` component that includes `<TouchableOpacity />` and its children. And send `banner, square, portrait, poster` as an array then map through them

Comment: You usually want to create the functions inside the `Collage` component (rather than receive them as props)

Comment: @Berci, yeah I made the custom component in my real code with that, and some custom styling. But, should I give to the childs components the press functionallity? I mean, what if that components might not have the press funcionallity in other screens, or what if they just update some parent state?

Comment: Other than the small improvement Berci wrote, there is nothing wrong with your approach. Your intention is to create a mapping between 4 different images and their behaviors, and that's exactly what the Collage component is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will extend the comment:

You either want to create the functions inside the Collage component (rather than receive them as props)

Or have an array of images sent to `View` component. Something like:

```
function Collage({ images }) {
   return (
       <View>
           images.map(image => (
             <Image key={`collage-image-${image.type}`} uri={image.uri} style={styles[image.type]} onClick={image.onClick} />
           )
       </View>
   );
}
```

where images is an array, each array element containing an uri, an type (which should be one of `banner, square, portrait, poster` in your case), and a click handler.

**Warning:** if you have multiple collages on the same page you might want to send some extra prop in order to ensure  that you won't have `two children with the same key`

Comment: `images` must be an object containing keys from `image.type` in your solution.

Comment: Yes, thank you! @Raul (as @Samet M. mentioned )You will receive a warning (and the it will hurt the performance) if you don't set the key for the `<Image` component inside the map. I will update the answer.